# Isn't Random defined in ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, random, undefined

My `ruby -v` is:
`ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]`

But trying to call Random results in the following error:
`uninitialized constant Random (NameError)`

Anyone knows a way to fix this?
I've heard around that Random was defined from 1.9.2. :(

Thank you.

Comment: It does. See above, and I just tried it too:
`ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410)`

`Random.new.rand => 0.439598974710974`

Comment: try `puts RUBY_VERSION` before using `Random` and make sure you are using 1.9.3 and not the system's default 1.8.7

Comment: please try ```::Random``` instead, might be a namespace issue. you can also try to execute it directly from the command prompt: ```ruby -e "puts Random.new.rand"```

Comment: Hey guys, tested all suggestions and @slivu was the right one. Thanks everybody.
This is kinda strange, though. I configured rvm to switch to 1.9.3 with my app folder, and it is working indeed. Actually i've run `ruby-v` from inside the directory. But surprisingly, Sublime is running on 1.8.7, just in the same folders. Looking for solving it now.

Comment: Well, @NickDeSteffen pointed a solution here: http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/switching-to-sublime-text-2, by using `rvm-auto-ruby`. Now Sublime Text seems to work along with rvmrc definitions.